# How to handle unknown number of parameters with Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I want to use JQuery's Sortable (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists), so my left list will end with something like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Some txt1 
        <input type="hidden" name="li1" value="1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        Some txt2 
        <input type="hidden" name="li2" value="2"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The number of `<li>` will be different every time. My idea is to get all hidden inputs values and names put them in array and POST the array as JSON data, but how should my Controller look like?
Is there a way to "wait" for list of something in the controller. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listItems")
    public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(@RequestParam(value = "items") List<NameIdPair> items){...}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can inject a instance of `Map` holding all parameters.

```
@RequestMapping("/listItems")
public @ResponseBody GridModel getUsersForGrid(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    params.get("parametername");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How does that look in Chrome in the http field when you enter an address?